# My Mongo item ID isn't getting pushed through the REST API

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express, mean-stack

So I am working on a blog site for class. My project is to create a REST API for a blog site. I can get everything to display from the database through .ejs views. My problem is the only thing not getting pushed through is when I need the blogID to update that specific blog with a submit button. Can anyone look at my code and help me? I have been at this for 6 days Googling and testing. Thanks.

```
<form method="put" action="/blogedit/<%= blogData.blogid %>" style="padding: 20px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="blogTitle"  class="text-dark">
          Blog Title
      </label>
      <input class="form-control"  id="blogTitle" name="blogTitle" value="<%= blogData.blogTitle %>">
          <label for="blogText" class="text-dark" style="width: 100%;">
              Blog Text
          </label>
          <input class="form-control" id="blogText" name="blogText" value="<%= blogData.blogText %>"></textarea>
           </div>
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Save">
      </div>
   </form>
```

Above is my html for the form I am trying to submit.

```
/*GET BLOG EDIT PAGE*/
module.exports.readOne = function (req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path;
    path = "/api/blog/" + req.params.blogid;
    requestOptions = {
        url: apiOptions.server + path,
        method: "GET",
        json: {}
    };
    request(
        requestOptions,
        function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                renderBlogEdit(req, res, body);
            }
        }
    );
};

/*Render BLOG EDIT PAGE */
var renderBlogEdit = function (req, res, blogData) {
    res.render('blogedit', {
        title: 'Edit Blog',
        pageHeader: {
            title: 'Edit Blog'
        },
        blogData: blogData,
        blogid: blogData._id,
        blogTitle: blogData.blogTitle,
        blogText: blogData.blogText
    });
};
/*Blog Edit Post*/
module.exports.editPost = function (req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path, postdata;
    path = '/api/blog/' + req.params.blogid;

    postdata = {
        blogTitle: req.body.blogTitle,
        blogText: req.body.blogText
    };

    requestOptions = {
        url: apiOptions.server + path,
        method: "PUT",
        json: postdata
    };
    request(
        requestOptions,
        function (err, response, body) {
            if (response.statusCode === 201) {
                res.redirect('/bloglist');
            } else {
                _showError(req, res, response.statusCode);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

This is my app_server controller for editing a blog and below will be my app_api function for editing a blog.

```
module.exports.readOne = function (req, res) {
    console.log('Finding blogs', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.blogid) {
        blogSch
            .findById(req.params.blogid)
            .exec(function (err, blog) {
                if (!blog) {
                    sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
                        "message": "blogid not found"
                    });
                    return;
                } else if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(blog);
                sendJsonResponse(res, 200, blog);
            });
    } else {
        console.log('No blogid in request');
        sendJsonResponse(res, 404, {
            "message": "No blogid in request"
        });
    }
};

module.exports.editOne = function (req, res) {
    console.log("Updating Blog Entry : " + req.params.blogid);
    console.log(req.body);
    blogSch.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.blogid },
        { $set: { "blogTitle": req.body.blogTitle } },
        { $set: { "blogText": req.body.blogText } },
        function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
            } else {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 201, response);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. For more clarification, when the submit button is hit on the form I just get a 404 error for the page not being found. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Where is the code for the route to `/blogedit` ? That's what you are getting 404 for and that error means it is **not found**. The most likely cause is that you have not actually defined a `POST` method for the route `/blogedit`. You have not included any code in your question that defines this route. So either show the code so we can point out what is wrong or possibly realize you never defined it.

Comment: See also [Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) in the express documentation.

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. It turns out that after I fixed the 404 error by adding the route to the page, the edit was not posting correctly because $set should only be called once with everything like this - {$set: {"blogTitle": req.body.blogTitle, "blogText": req.body."blogText"}} not twice like I have it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At initial glance you have invalid html for your form. A HTML5 form can only have the methods 'POST' and 'GET'. Since PUT is invalid, the form is being treated as a GET request which is what's giving you your 404 page.

Change your code to use POST on both the HTML5 form and the server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just tried that and still getting a 404 error. When I choose the edit button for the blog from the list page is renders /blogedit/blogid where blog id is a super long mongo id. The form is still not receiving the id and still getting a 404 in the actual edit view.